# How to make the contents of the left div bang the right div?

Tags: html, css

I need to force the contents of the left div to flow around the right when it is located.

```css
.class1 {
  background-color: #678e6f;
  width: 80%;
  float: left;
}

.class2 {
  background-color: #00ff34;
  width: 300px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="class">
  <div class="class1">
    <img/><img/><img/>
  </div>
  <div class="class2">
    <li>text</li>
  </div>
</div>
```

but when colliding divs
tolerated completely right

I need something like this just to transfer all the elements.
http://htmlbook.ru/example/

Is it possible to do something like this?

Comment: the link to the example posted is inaccessible. a screenshot may be better in this case. Sounds like a need for flexbox though...

Comment: By the way, the wording of your question is a bit  confusing, you may want to consider rephrasing it..

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems with your example, but if you want text to flow around an image (or any div) that is on the right, it would look more or less like this:

```
.classContainer {
   background-color: #678e6f;
}

.classFloat {
   background-color: #00ff34;
   width: 300px;
   float: right;
   margins: 10px; /* you probably want margins! */
}
```

And then the HTML:

```
<div class="classContainer">
  <div class="classFloat">
    <img /> <!-- here is an image the text would flow around. -->
  </div>
  <p>Here is the material that will flow around the floating div.</p>
</div>
```

It doesn't matter which is text and image, of course; or they could both be text or both images. The content is irrelevant. But flowing images around text would be unusual!